# Around what percentage of universities require(d) Ancient Greek and Latin for admissions?

Tags: reference-request, academic-history

I limit this question to universities in Canada, UK, and the US. 
 In general:

Please see the titled question, and provide dates if known.

2 Examples: p. 10 of 17 [of this PDF](https://www.oxfordenglish.co.uk/PDF/Oxford/Everything%20you%20need%20to%20know%20about%20the%20University%20of%20Oxford.pdf) states Oxford University's admissions requirement of Ancient Greek until 1920 and Latin until 1960.
[This Quora answer](http://qr.ae/RNzZUg) quotes [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801878896):

> In 1883, the last year in which the classical languages were compulsory for Harvard freshman, all studied Latin and Greek.

Comment: I added the [tag:reference-request] tag because presumably a good answer to this question would need to cite supporting documentation...

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because I don't think it is relevant to the site. I think it would be a better fit at history stackexchange, or something similar.

Comment: @Johanna I am upvoting because I think that it is an interesting piece of the history of academia, and I'd really like to know the answer.

Comment: @jakebeal While I'm also really curious about this question, wouldn't it be more suited for the history stackexchange site? Not trying to ruffle any feathers or be a contrarian, I just haven't seen many questions in this vein in my (very short) time as an Academia.SE user.

Comment: @Simoo My attempt at History SE [here](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/23509/8309) was (wrongfully?) closed as off-topic, but I question its closure [here](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/2178/8309). Nevertheless, I posted here because a question about the history of unis, should be on-topic here?

Comment: If the question were phrased as "How many universities require Ancient Greek or Latin", I think it would be clearly on-topic, even if easily answered with "none". I don't see that asking a question about practices in academia from a historical perspective makes a question off-topic.

Comment: We can let this stay here for a bit to see if it gets any answers, but honestly I agree that you're more likely to get answers on [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @eykanal Thanks. Did you read my comment above: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49163/what-rough-percentage-of-universities-required-ancient-greek-and-latin-from-whe?noredirect=1#comment114014_49163?

Comment: @LePressentiment - Ach, no I did not, thanks for highlighting. (Bad moderator, no biscuit.) We get questions of this type from time to time, where it's not clear where it's a best fit, and unfortunately they tend to go unanswered. Typically, it's because it requires a lot of multidisciplinary knowledge (history of academia and scientific study in this case) which is tough to find. I'll leave it open, but I'm kinda pessimistic about you getting a good answer.

Comment: One of the stated goals of the forum is to answer questions regarding requirements and expectations of academicians. While it may be a stretch this question goes to a perspective on how those requirements and expectations changed over the course of the 20th century. Those of us in the Biological and Health Sciences are still immersed in Greek and Latin terminology, even though proficiency in those disciplines is no longer required and the overwhelming shift has been to English. Many suggest that German be studied by Chemists and Physicists so that they can read seminal works untranslated.

Comment: Also remember that those requirements were in place as a way of maintaining exclusivity. Only the elites or the very motivated would have been trained in Ancient Greek and Latin, and as a result, only that strata of society was selected to the academy. The twentieth century saw an unprecedented democratization of advanced education and like the Protestant Reformation before it came from the a transition to the vernacular. In a day and age where even an undergraduate degree does not often fulfill the minimum requirements for many careers, a perspective on how we got here is important.

Comment: If this were about requirements for admission of graduate schools, I would say it would be on-topic. But, **...** . I vote to close as off-topic because it's an undergraduate issue.

Comment: While I disagree with that this question is off-topic here, I think it will be on-topic on [hsm.se]. See in particular their [academia](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academia) tag.

Comment: I believe that much more germane is the overall ambiguity of the question. Require Latin and Greek for what? All majors? Graduate students? Undergraduate general education? Some still require it for certain majors, and likely always will (e.g. no self-respecting classicist can't read ancient greek), and others might not, even when it seems like they would.

Comment: My mother studied Philology (with specialization in Lithuanian language) in Vilnius State University (Lithuania) from 1960 till 1965. Not only these studies included both Latin and ancient Greek, but also one of the tasks was to translate significant part of Iliad. She worked as a senior teacher and the school director assistant for many years afterwards. I have studied Biology in the same university thirty years later. We had some introductory Latin course (biologists need to remember lots of Latin names of animals, plants and fungi), but it was not deep enough to learn speaking or reading ar

Comment: _I vote to close as off-topic because it's an undergraduate issue_ — No, it's a university administration issue.

Comment: As user6726 suggested, I think the question should be reworded as present tense "What rough percentage of universities require Ancient Greek and Latin?". I think the user should make another post in History of Science and Mathematics for the '..from when to when?' part.

Comment: Not quite an answer (because small sample and not US) but according to the website of [Uni Würzburg](https://www.uni-wuerzburg.de/fuer/studierende/zsb/info/latinum_graecum_hebraicum/), Latin is a prerequisite for the first state exam of high school teachers in Bavaria in the following subjects: German, English, French, History, Italian, Katholic Religion, Spanish, Greek. And Ancient Greek is a prerequisite for the first state exam of high school teachers of Latin and Katholic Religion. Also, Latin and / or Ancient Greek is required for a number of Philology, History and Archeology degrees.

Comment: Oh, I thought the OP was talking about today.If the OP is referring to the past then the question should be reformulated: **What was the percentage of anglophone universities that required Ancient Greek and Latin?** The "when" question in the title isn't strictly essential.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any "major" or "top tier" universities in the USA have any language requirements other than English. Even then, you don't really have to speak English as much as be able to manage HW's and exams in English.

St. Johns would certainly appreciate it but most courses won't read classics in their native language.

My friend is finishing a PhD in classical history at an Ivy League program and he was unique in his knowledge of Latin from high school. I'm pretty sure 0 colleges require Latin or Greek.

Comment: HW refers to what?

Comment: HW is short for home work

Comment: Foreigners are often required to take the TOEFL test of English and have a certain score.